# Solved: Arduino/C++ Library issues: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I'm currently working on programming a MeArm in C++ and using it as an Arduino library. I've made a ServoMotor class that inherits functions from the Servo library. The cantino library in the ControlArmSetup.ino is a library that makes it possible to use simple C++ functions such as int main() and cin, cout.

Error Message

```
C:\Users\Britt\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgSIiji.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `__main__': 
C:\Users\Britt\OneDrive\Documenten\Arduino\libraries\MeArm\ControlArmSetup/ControlArmSetup.ino:8: undefined reference to `ServoMotor::ServoMotor(int, int, int)'
C:\Users\Britt\OneDrive\Documenten\Arduino\libraries\MeArm\ControlArmSetup/ControlArmSetup.ino:9: undefined reference to `ServoMotor::attach(int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ServoMotor.h

```
#ifndef ServoMotor_h
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define ServoMotor_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Servo.h"

class ServoMotor : public Servo {

  private:
    const int MAX_ROT;
    const int MIN_ROT;

  public:
    ServoMotor(int _MAX_ROT, int _MIN_ROT, int _pin);
    int current_position;
    int pin;
    void write(int newPos);
    void attach(int pinMotor);
};
#endif
#endif
```

ServoMotor.cpp

```
#include <Servo.h>

class ServoMotor : public Servo {
  private:
    int MAX_ROT;
    int MIN_ROT;

  public:
    int pin;

    ServoMotor(int _MAX_ROT, int _MIN_ROT, int _pin) : Servo(){
      MAX_ROT = _MAX_ROT;
      MIN_ROT = _MIN_ROT;
      pin = _pin;
    }

    void write(int newPos){
      Servo::write(newPos);
    }

    void attach(int pinMotor){
      Servo::attach(pinMotor);
    }
};
```

ControlArmSetup.ino

```
#include "ServoMotor.h"

#include <cantino.h>

using namespace cantino;

int main () {
   ServoMotor tester(0, 180, 9);
   tester.attach(tester.pin);
   return 0;
}
```

The cpp and header files are located in the same folder as the ino program. They appear as tabs when opening the ControlArmSetup sketch.

Using ServoMotor:: with functions hasn't helped. I'm not sure if it is connected to an error in my code, or if it has to do with file locations. I've looked at some other questions, but following multiple answers hasn't helped (changing file locations, using ServoMotor::, #ifdef __cplusplus).

Thanks in advance!

**Edit: Solution**

As John Filleau and David Hammen said, I didn't link my header file in my cpp file, which caused my error.

Comment: A .cpp file should include its corresponding .h file. `ServoMotor.cpp` should `#include "ServoMotor.h"`. Then you don't need to redeclare the class like you're doing. The definitions in `ServorMotor.cpp` end up looking like `ServoMotor::ServoMotor(ServoMotor(int _MAX_ROT, int _MIN_ROT, int _pin) : Servo(){...etc` without the enclosing `class ServoMotor`.

Comment: You aren't compiling ServoMotor.cpp or aren't linking ServoMotor.o into your executable.

Comment: Wow. Thank you both! I think my understanding of header and cpp files was a bit mixed. Feels like a bit of a rookie mistake, but glad it's fixed!